# Horizontal align text in multiple columns

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

I want to achieve something like this,

```
1. Question One             The answer to the question.

2. Question Two             The answer to the question
                            that can span across multiple
                            lines because it is long.

3. Sometimes the question   Only one line answer
   can span across multi-
   ple line but have one
   answer.

4. Sometimes the question   The answers can also have
   can have multiple        multiple lines and one thing
   lines.                   notice is that there is
                            enumeration as well.
```

I tried `multicol`, `tabbing`, `multienum` environment but can't do this.

Comment: A table with three columns?

Comment: Should the question and answer columns be equally wide?

Comment: What is the other column for? I need two columns. And tables will float. I don't don't want it to. And no, the question column is shorter than the answer column.

Comment: A first col for the numbers

Comment: And I meant a `tabular` not a `table` environment.  `tabular`s don't float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion with automatic question counting at the beginning of the first column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{questioncnt}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\raggedleft\stepcounter{questioncnt}\thequestioncnt.\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{N{2cm}p{5cm}p{6cm}}
  & \blindtext & \blindtext \tabularnewline
  & \blindtext & \blindtext \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Another example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{questioncnt}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\raggedleft\stepcounter{questioncnt}\thequestioncnt.\arraybackslash}R{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{N{2cm}L{6cm}L{6cm}}
  & What is the meaning of life? & foo \tabularnewline
  & What is the answer to any question in the universe? & Of course, there is only one answer and the answer can only be \huge 42 \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice!  And can you add ragged right to the text columns easily?  With the OP text you get overfull boxes with such narrow widths.

Comment: This is what I want. But, can this be done by avoiding counters and using enumerate instead?

Comment: @Ayatana: No, `enumerate` is not very useful here, in my point of view. By the way, `enumerate` uses counters too ;-)

Comment: Sorry, can you modify you code to accept newline that stay in the same column. `\\\` starts a new row in the table.

Comment: @Ayatana: Use `\newline` instead of `\\`